# multi-label text classification with feedback

Tags: python, deep-learning, classification, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I'm currently working on a multi-label multi-class text classification problem.
In some part of the problem I need to give feedback to user that based on which features, words or phrases the algorithm decide to classify an instance to a certain category?

For example for a text like `A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R` I need output like this:
[image]

How can I consider this problem? what is the name or keywords of this problems? Is there any ready python package for this type of problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is **interpretability** in machine learning (ml) models. There is much [discussion](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/04/model-interpretability-neural-networks-deep-learning.html) on this topic and is steadily gaining more attention, as more real-world applications in important subjects such as [terrorism detection](https://www.engineering.com/DesignerEdge/DesignerEdgeArticles/ArticleID/14426/Big-Data-Predicts-Terrorist-Attacks-with-More-Than-90-Accuracy.aspx), [precision-medicine](http://www.healthcareitnews.com/news/google-makes-ai-tool-precision-medicine-open-source) etc. incorporate ml components.

There is at least one python module already doing what you seem to ask for, named [lime](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime).

If you are interested in the task in general, there are many other resources you can also check out (e.g. an [extended presentation](http://people.csail.mit.edu/beenkim/papers/BeenK_FinaleDV_ICML2017_tutorial.pdf) and [article](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/ideas-on-interpreting-machine-learning), [conferences](http://interpretable.ml/) etc.).